# what‘s the difference between shell-cmd ’dmesg‘ and file ’/var/log/dmesg‘

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I think the ouput of the command `dmesg` should be the subset of the file `/var/log/dmesg`.
But when I am debugging,the segmentation fault information can only be seen in the output of the command `dmesg`.

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel message buffer is a ring buffer with limited space - when new messages arrive old may get dropped.

`dmesg` outputs the current buffer.

Normally `/var/log/dmesg` is filled directly after boot, so that the boot messages do not get lost.